# Is there a way to specify a precedence among user defined conversions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, implicit-conversion, ambiguous

Disclaimer: I know that using user defined implicit conversions is often discouraged. However, in our project, we need these conversions for various template classes to work well with each other.

I need to define a precedence of user defined conversions, e.g.:

```
struct X{}
struct Y{}

struct Z{
    operator X(){...}
    operator Y(){...}
}

void foo(X x){...}
void foo(Y y){...}

// somewhere in some template client code
...{
    Z z = ...;
    ...
    foo(z); // WILL NOT COMPILE
}
```

This will not compile, as the conversion from `Z` to either `X` or `Y` is ambiguous. **Is there a way to resolve this ambiguity. I.e, can I somehow tell the compiler: if there is a function overloaded for `X` and `Y`, then prefer to cast `Z` to `X` instead of failing to compile.**

I know that there is no simple way to specify this. But maybe some template magic and a wrapping template struct that I am not aware of might do the trick. I am allowed to change the client code. I cannot use an explicit cast, as the client code is a templated code that is not aware about the type `Z` and the available overloads of `foo`.

Comment: I can by rewriting `foo`?

Comment: 1. Can you modify the templates also? 2. Can you show us an example of a template that doesn't do what you want?

Comment: What is the differentiating factor when deciding which flavor of `foo` you want to call?

Comment: @JohnDibling: I always want to prefer `foo(X)` over `foo(Y)` if such `foo`s exist (which is not always the case). If only a `foo(Y)` exists, I want the conversion to `Y`. If only a `foo(X)` exists, then the conversion to `X`, of course.

Comment: Sounds like a case for SFINAE

Comment: Is the only thing you can do is modify `Z`?  If so you are out of luck.  If I can do stuff at other points I can solve it.  But need clarification from gexicide.

Comment: @Yakk: No, I can modify everything. However, the code that uses `foo(z)` may *not* hardcode the cast (e.g., not simply `static_cast` to `X`), because the code should be independent from the types to which `Z` can be cast. I.e., the code that calls `foo(z)` may neither mention `X` nor `Y`.

Comment: So we can fix `foo` to understand to prefer `X` over `Y`, or I can set up a complex system to take a `foo` function proxy and an argument and ask the argument which it prefers.  First is way easier.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, fixing `foo` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like "prioritized call", with a pattern like this:

```
struct P2 {};
struct P1: P2 {};

template<class A> 
void foo(A x, P1, typename std::common_type<X,A>::type* =nullptr) 
{ foo(static_cast<X>(x)); }

template<class A> 
void foo(A y, P2, typename std::common_type<Y,A>::type* =nullptr) 
{ foo(static_cast<Y>(y)); }

template<class A> void foo(A a) { foo(a,P1()); }
```

being P2 a base for P1 and the call made with P1, if common_type can compile, the first version goes. If it cannot compile, the first version is like not existent (SFINAE) and the second goes. If it cannot compile as well ... if A is just X or just Y the respective original foo is called, otherwise this cannot compile being types incompatible.

Note that you can even generalize the "priority" as

```
template<size_t N> struct P: P<N+1> {}
template<> struct P<10> {}
```

declare SFINAE functions taking `P<1>`, `P<2>` etc. up to `P<10>`, and place the root call with `P<0>()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little system that smart casts a variable to to a sequence of types `Ts...` such that the first element in the list `Ts...` that the variable implicitly converts to is the one chosen:

```
namespace details {
  template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
  template<class U, class Types, class=void>
  struct smart_cast_t:std::false_type {
    using type=U;
    template<class A>
    U operator()(A&& a)const{return std::forward<A>(a);}
  };
  template<class U, class T0, class...Ts>
  struct smart_cast_t<
    U, types<T0, Ts...>,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T0>::value>::type
  >:std::true_type
  {
    using type=T0;
    template<class A>
    T0 operator()(A&& a)const{return std::forward<A>(a);}
  };
  template<class U, class T0, class...Ts>
  struct smart_cast_t<
    U, types<T0, Ts...>,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<U, T0>::value>::type
  >:smart_cast_t< U, types<Ts...> >
  {};
}

template<class... Ts, class U>
auto smart_cast( U&& u )
-> decltype(details::smart_cast_t< U, details::types<Ts...> >{}( std::forward<U>(u) ))
{
  return details::smart_cast_t< U, details::types<Ts...> >{}( std::forward<U>(u) );
}
```

Now, the idea is that we can now modify `foo` as follows:

```
void foo_impl(X);
void foo_impl(Y);

template<class A>
void foo(A&& a) {
  foo_impl( smart_cast<X, Y>(std::forward<A>(a)) );
}
```

and `foo` casts the `A` to `X` if possible, and if not to `Y`.

We could write up an entire system whereby we pass in a description of the overloads of `foo` in a package like `types< types<X,Y> >` and an overload set of `foo` to some magic code, which spits out a dispatcher, but that would be over engineering.

[live example](http://ideone.com/FZB4K1)

This uses C++11 features.  With C++14 we get to drop some verbage in `smart_cast`.

The design is pretty simple.  We create a `types` bundle to work with bundles of types (just boilerplate).

Then our `details::smart_cast_t` has a fallback base specialization that just converts our `U` to `U`.  If we can convert `U` to the first type, we do so. Otherwise, we recurse on our parent type, possibly terminating in the base specialization.

I hide that in details, so our public function is simple -- it is `smart_cast< type1, type2, type3, etc >( expression )`.  We don't have to pass `U` the type of the expression, as we deduce it, then pass it into details for the work to be done.

At run time this reduces to a single implicit cast: all the above is what is done at compile time.

About the only downside is that this can result in warnings on some compilers, as we use implicit conversion.  Add a `static_cast<T0>` to the first non-base specialization of `smart_cast_t` to avoid this.

I inherited `smart_cast_t` from `true_type` and `false_type` needlessly.  This means that the value of `smart_cast_t<U, types<Ts...>>::value` will tell you if `U` converted to any of `Ts...`, or was just left alone as a `U`.

The caller is responsible for rvalue vs lvalue categories.  If the cast fails, it will return a `U` not a `U&&` if passed an rvalue.  The fallback -- to `U` -- I think will generate better error messages, but if you prefer that `smart_cast<int, double>(std::string("hello"))` fail to compile instead of returning a `std::string`, simply remove the `operator()` from the base specialization of `smart_cast_t`.

Speaking of which, I also don't work right for `smart_cast<int, double>("")`.  Might need some `typename std::decay<U>::type`s or something in there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cast it explicitly:

```
foo(static_cast<Y>(z));
```

Comment: This is not possible. The client code is a template code which does not know about 1) which overloads are available for `foo` and 2) which casts are available for `z`. It is all determined by the template parameters. I have clearified my question.